# My Computer Doesn't Realize ESP8266 ESP-05 is Connected or not

Tags: wifi, esp8266

I wired ESP-05 to my usb-to-ttl as images below.

I connected it to USB #2 port, and my computer seems not knowing this.
[image]

I also tried to send "AT+RST" through Realterm but, it didn't work neither.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you try to describe what is happening and what the expected outcome of the action should be, maybe what you have tried. From what i can see everything looks fine, the RX/TX connection is where most people do wrong, but it looks like it is connected properly.

Comment: your problem is not with the ESP, but with the usb-ttl converter. You need to install manually the PL2303 driver.